# Jest having trouble mocking specific function

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I've started using jest but I've been having some trouble mocking specific JS functions, I've already tried various would be solutions to this but i just couldn't get it to work.

Below is my JavaScript function code

functions.js :

```
function test1(){

return "hello1"
}

function test2(){

return "hello2"
}
module.exports = test1;
module.exports = test2;
```

and this is my jest code:

```
function.test.js

const testfunction = require('/function');

test('tooltip Correct DOM element test', () => {
    expect(testfunction.test1).toBe("hello1");
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are exporting the function incorrectly. You need to do:

```
function test1() {
  return "hello1"
}

function test2() {
  return "hello2"
}
module.exports = {
  test1: test1,
  test2: test2
};
```

Exporting the function in this way will enable to get `testfunction.test1` inside the test file. And you need to call the function inside the test script like:

```
expect(testfunction.test1()).toBe("hello1");
```